# Find CDF of random variable

Tags: probability-theory

A random variable X is drawn from a uniform distribution on interval [0,1]

Consider random variable Y=Sqrt(X)-1, find it's Cumulative distribution function FY(y).

I suppose it will be
0 for y<=-1,
(y+1)^2 y>-1 & y<=0 ,
1 otherwise
What's wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong.

Comment: Formatting your (correct) answer in mathjax gives $$F_Y(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \mbox{if $y\leq -1$} \\ (y+1)^2 & \mbox{if $-1<y\leq 0$} \\ 1 & \mbox{ otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$